# Provide input for visual studio add-in

Tags: visual-studio-addins

How can I provide input parameters (like text to be written in a file) using a Visual Studio Add-In? Can I use the **ref object varIn** parameter of the Exec method  and if I can how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I can use s simple Windows Form to collect the input, nothing special related to Visual Studio is needed.